# Running one-off Flyway commands such as "info" on Heroku

Tags: heroku, flyway

I am just wondering how to run one-off Flyway commands such as info on Heroku.

My application already manages its migrations for itself by running the migrate command on startup.

But I am not sure how to run commands such as info (http://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/info.html); that is independently of my application: which of the different execution modes should I choose and how should I execute the info command for instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke it programmatically from the instance and react on or display the results yourself. Or you can run it from your machine using any client (commandline or other) and connect to Heroku PostgreSQL from there.

Comment: Thanks Axel. I understand the second solution. However can you please explain a bit further what you mean by "You can invoke it programmatically from the instance and react on or display the results yourself."

Comment: It meant use Flyway.info()

Comment: You mean after having uploaded the flyway client to Heroku?